# I want to ask you how get rid of typeerror

Tags: python

[image]

I'm making a progarm that compute lat and lon
when I run the program there is an error.
File "./latlon_calc.py", line 25, in 
latdisc = latdis * 1 / 11100
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
How can i fix it?

Comment: Please read [ask].

Comment: Note that StackOverflow posting guidelines discourage images rather than the text of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `latdis` you are receiving as input is of string type you can cast it to int simply by doing `latdis = int(input(...))`